# Append to json matching by key

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have json like this (no.1)

```
[
 {
   'id': 1,
   'data': '...'
 },
 {
   'id': 2,
   'data': '...'
 }
]
```

and i want to append into this other json which looks like (no.2)

```
[
 {
   'id': 1,
   'data_additional': '...'
 },
 {
   'id': 2,
   'data_additional': '...',
 }
]
```

and the output should look like: (no1 + no2)

```
[
 {
   'id': 1,
   'data': '...',
   'data_additional': '...'
 },
 {
   'id': 2,
   'data': '...',
   'data_additional': '...'
 }
]
```

how can i do this in python?
i tried to do it using for loop, is there any other way to do this?

```
no3 = {}
if len(no1) == len(no2):
  for x in range(len(no1)):
    for y in range(len(no2)):
      if no1[x]['id'] == no2[y]['id']:
        no3[x].append({**no1[x], **no2[y]})
```

Comment: Can you please show what code you wrote so far?

Comment: Post that try of loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like the below (no need for an external library)

```
d1 = [
 {
   'id': 1,
   'data': 'WWW'
 },
 {
   'id': 2,
   'data': 'KKK'
 }
]

d2 = [
 {
   'id': 1,
   'data_additional': 'AAA'
 },
 {
   'id': 2,
   'data_additional': 'BBB',
 }
]
#
# assuming the lists are sorted by id
#
data = []
for idx,entry in enumerate(d1,):
    data.append(entry)
    data[-1].update(d2[idx])
print(data)
```

output

```
[{'id': 1, 'data': 'WWW', 'data_additional': 'AAA'}, {'id': 2, 'data': 'KKK', 'data_additional': 'BBB'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `pandas`' `join` method for simplicity and speed:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(json1).set_index('id')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(json2).set_index('id')

df1.join(df2).reset_index().to_dict(orient='records')
```

The `set_index` calls ensure that `join` will join records by id. `reset_index` makes sure that calling `to_dict` (to transform the data frame back to json) will also include the ids.

Comment: thanks, i dont want to install pandas on my server, but the solution is great